# Diffeomorphism between $SO(3)$ and $\mathbb{R}P^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, projective-space, grassmannian

I am curious if one can find a diffeomorphism between $SO(3)=\{A\in M_3(\mathbb{R}): AA^T=I_3 \text{ and det(A)=1} \}$ and $\mathbb{R}P^3$ using Grassmannian manifolds. I have seen multiple proofs regarding this using facts from Lie groups or just explicit calculations. For $m\leq n$ we denote the Grassmanian $G(m,n)=\{m-\text{dimensional subspace of }\mathbb{R}^n \}$ and it obtains a manifold structure throughout the projection map $\pi:F(m,n)\rightarrow G(m,n)$ where $F(m,n)$ are matrices of rank $m$ and also:
$$
\pi([r_1 \cdots r_m]^T)=span\{r_1,\ldots,r_n \}\quad \text{for n dimensional vectors $r_i$}
$$
Taking into account from linear algebra that:
$$
span\{r_1,\ldots,r_m \}=span\{y_1,\ldots,y_m \}\iff \exists B\in GL_m(\mathbb{R}) \text{ such }[x_1\cdots x_m]^T=B[y_1\cdots y_m]
$$
So this way we can find that the Grassmanian is the preimage of $m\times m$ submatrices of the determinant on $\mathbb{R}-\{0 \}$ and its dimension will be $m(n-m$). Genuinely the main fact we use is that:

$$
\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))=\bigcup_{B\in GL_m(\mathbb{R})} B V
$$
Where U is matrix that has the unitary $I_m$ as submatrix and V also has the unitary $I_m$ as a submatrix (we may permute the columns that give us $I_m$ as a submatrix). We also know that $G(1,n+1)\cong \mathbb{R}P^{n}$. So one expects that $G(1,4)\cong \mathbb{R}P^3\cong SO(3)$. So is it possible to attain this result by proving that $G(1,4)\cong \mathbb{R}P^3$. I believe that it can be done since we use matrix descriptions for elements in the Grassmannian. Any help corrections or ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: The standard approach uses quaternions. Let $\mathbb{I}$ denote the $3$-dimensional space of imaginary quaternions with the standard inner product. Any unit quaternion $u$ defines a map $R_u: \mathbb{I} \rightarrow \mathbb{I}$. It is easy to check that $|R_u(q)| = |q|$ and has positive determinant when written as a matrix. Therefore, $u\mapsto R_u$ is a smooth map $S^3 \rightarrow SO(3)$. However, $R_{-u} = R_u$ and therefore it is really a map $\mathbb{R}P^3 \rightarrow S(O(3)$. It is straightforward to check that it is a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Think of protective space as a closed 3-ball of radius $\pi$ with antipodal points on the boundary identified. Then, each  point represents a rotation about that axis with angle equal to the length of the the vector.